# Will Nintendo eShop cards work cross-region?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-eshop

I am from Singapore, which uses the American region for 3DSes and eShop cards. A friend bought me a 3DS from America when he went there. I set my NNID to Brazil to be able to use the eShop. Will I be able to use eShop cards from Singapore (US region cards) on the Brazilian eShop?

Answer (score 3):

The Nintendo eShop cards are region-locked. Cards from the PAL region only work in PAL consoles, and cards from Japan only work in Japanese consoles et cetera.

**Fortunately**, in your case, you will be able to redeem codes from cards that were purchased from Singapore, because Brazil and Singapore **both** actually belong to the North America region, as stated in [Nintendo Wiki](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Regions#North_America_.28NTSC-U.29).